# How to interact with Access DB hosted on Sharepoint Online via Public Website?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-access, public-website

I have data in an Access DB which is hosted on Sharepoint Online. I would like to build a website where users can query the DB via an interface that I can style via HTML and CSS. I am a brand new Sharepoint Online customer as of today.

Now that MS has changed to 3rd party only for the Public Website in Sharepoint, how do I proceed to build a webpage that will connect to the hosted DB?

I am starting with a fresh DB, sitting in Sharepoint Online right now.

I know the next step is to secure a domain and get hosting, but then what?

I'm just asking to be pointed in the right direction, not asking someone to have to write out the steps.